# Jquery Address или похожие библиотеки

Tags: jquery, ajax, address

Подскажите, столкнулся с вот такой вот проблемой. Нужно, чтобы на сайте работал ajax с изменением url страницы по выполнению! Но как-то не очень идет с ним. Подскажите, есть ли ещё тому подобные библиотеки? С таким же функционалом.

PS: случайно не знаете туториалов хороших про `ajax + change link` систему? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HTML5 History API уже сегодня и без ограничений](http://habrahabr.ru/post/144071/).